# White box appearing at the bottom of the page when using antd Modal on mobile Firefox

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I am using antd with React. I have a couple of Modals in my code. They work perfectly fine on web Chrome and Firefox as well as on mobile Chrome. However when using Firefox on mobile, I get a white box at the bottom of the page. Any ideas?

```
.ant-layout {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: @background;
  padding: 0 1.8em 1.5em 1.8em;
}

.ant-layout-content {
  padding: 0 2em 1.5em 2em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 730px) {
  .ant-layout-content {
    padding: 0;
  }
}

header.ant-layout-header {
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
}

footer.ant-layout-footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: @primary;
  color: @white;
  text-align: center;
}

.ant-modal-body {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 210px);
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.ant-modal-body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: No idea, it would be hard to say anything without checking the code.  This white box could be from the browser itself. Something related to scroll

Comment: I've added the LESS code of my antd layout and modal components. I think it might have something to do with the height of the content

Comment: Yes, it could be either height or padding. If you want I can help you to debug it

Comment: Yes please, I will send you an email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default when ant design renders Modals. It renders them inside `<Body />`. Which could create an issue with overflow. Try to render modal inside, the first child of the body element (it could be `#root`). It should work.

To target the `#root` element you need to use `getContainer` function from ant design.

```
<Modal getContainer="#root" ... />
```

https://ant.design/components/modal/#API -> search for `getContainer`

Answer (score 0):

adding overflow-x : hidden to the html tag was the reason for the whitebox showing up when image preview was clicked .

also happen when i opened modals on the same page . In modals i added getContainer="false" and it that worked .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).